# ModelAdmin ManyToManyField can be empty?

Tags: django

I have the class `Tag` with `ManyToManyField`:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    templates = ManyToManyField(Template, related_name='tags')
```

And `TagAdmin` class in `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

@admin.register(models.Tag)
class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
```

In django-admin require select at once value for field `templates`. But I don't want it! How I can use admin without required field `templates`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking for. It seems like you want to create instances of `Tag` without any `templates`. If so, you need to update the `Tag` model to make the `templates` field optional

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    templates = ManyToManyField(Template, related_name='tags', null=True, blank=True)
```